# Date specific queries to AWS neptune using java bolt driver

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cypher, amazon-neptune, bolt

I want to add edges to AWS neptune Graph DB using bolt java driver. And one of the property of the edge contains date and time. But it seems that neptune supports java.util.Date Object but bolt driver doesn't supports java.util.Date Object and It supports java.time.LocalDateTime Object. Is there any way to solve this problem ? Adding some more details below which may help.

Bolt driver version: 4.3.3

Java version: Java 11 (I am running the code from AWS Lambda which doesn't supports java later than java11)

**My sample code is as below:**

Maven Dependency:

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
```

Java Code to write the data to AWS Neptune Graph DB:

```
Driver boltDriver = GraphDatabase.driver(neptuneConnectionString,
                    Config.builder().withConnectionTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .withEncryption()
                            .withTrustStrategy(Config.TrustStrategy.trustSystemCertificates())
                            .build());

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        allParameters.put("locationId", "dsfsdf3453");
        allParameters.put("deviceId", "fdfdf4534");
        allParameters.put("edgeId", "dfdf45345");
        allParameters.put("loginAt", LocalDateTime.now());

var query = "MERGE (l:Location_J {locationId: $locationId}) MERGE (d:Device_J {deviceId: $deviceId}) MERGE (l)-[a:ACCESSES_J {loginAt: $loginAt}]->(d)";

boltDriver.session().run(query, parameters);
```

I am getting below exception:

````
WARNING: [0x06247997][uat-niyothon-neptune-2023.cluster-cfg5tfk5qker.ap-south-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182][021cdffffe623928-000035fc-0000b02d-f131b528da33cefe-05e79a93] Fatal error occurred in the pipeline
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.DatabaseException: "Unexpected server exception 'Operation terminated (internal error)'"
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:90)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:108)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.unpackFailureMessage(CommonMessageReader.java:83)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.read(CommonMessageReader.java:59)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1368)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1234)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1280)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Amazon Neptune integration with the Java Bolt client does not support use of the Java `LocalDateTime` class.

You can however use the `datetime` function and add the date information to the query that way (as a string). For example:

```
MERGE (l:Location_J {locationId: $locationId}) 
MERGE (d:Device_J {deviceId: $deviceId}) 
MERGE (l)-[a:ACCESSES_J {loginAt: datetime('2023-04-07T16:44:19Z'}]->(d)
```

or, using the parameterized form

```
MERGE (l:Location_J {locationId: $locationId}) 
MERGE (d:Device_J {deviceId: $deviceId}) 
MERGE (l)-[a:ACCESSES_J {loginAt: datetime($myDatetimeString)}]->(d)
```

The key part being, that for right now, the date parameter needs to be provided as a string.